# How do you assign a role to a user in pycord?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have a discord bot that needs to add someone to the ban watch list, which is a role.
But so far, all I can find are discord.py solutions, and since discord.py is discontinued, I use pycord instead. The bot has full admin privileges, so those are no worry.

```
dmchannel = await user.create_dm()
dmchannel.send(f"<@{user.id}> You have been put on the ban watch list! Be careful, you could be banned soon.")
# Add the role here
```

How would I manage to do this?

Comment: Just a tip, you can use `{user.mention}` to mention a user instead of `<@{user.id}>`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to add a role

### 1. `member.add_roles(role)`

Where member is [`discord.Member`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#member) and role is [`discord.Role`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#role) and we are using the [`add_roles()`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) method to add the role which takes the role as a parameter.
You can get the role from the [`guild.get_role()`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) method which takes the role ID as a parameter or u can use [`discord.utils.get(guild.roles , name="name")`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.utils.get) to get it from its name
then use that role to add to the member

### 2. `member.edit(roles=roles)`

You need to get all roles first with the [`member.roles`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Member.roles) attribute which returns a list of all roles the member has then u can append the role to the list. `roles.append(role)` the use [`member.edit(roles)`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Member.edit) this will add that role to the member

Answer (score 0):

You can get the role using **discord utils**, then using `member.add_roles()`:

```py
member = #member
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=#role name)
member.add_roles(role)
```